# Uninstall Kubernetes from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubernetes

I used below mentioned commands to remove kubernetes from my ubuntu 18.04 server.

```
kubeadm reset
sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*   
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo rm -rf ~/.kube
```

but still its showing :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server `localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?   while running kubectl version .
```

How can i completely remove `kubectl` from my ubuntu server 18.04 ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the method you chose in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/, it can be any of these:

Install kubectl binary via curl: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/kubectl`

Download as part of the Google Cloud SDK: `gcloud components remove kubectl`

Install with snap on Ubuntu (just as Gparmar said): `snap remove kubectl`

In addition, you may need to remove the configuration files in `~/.kube.`

Comment: @Niladri Dey , was removing `kubectl` worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you exectute commands below:

```
kubeadm reset
sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*   
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo rm -rf ~/.kube
```

**remember to restart computer.**

Comment: you mean restart my aws instance ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Does it help ?

Comment: not at all ....i did that but still while i use kubectl version ..it shows the version exist